# poLCA in R is not executing. I am getting a weird error message

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and I'm encountering an error that I'm not sure why I'm getting. I'm running R Studio Version 1.3.959 on Windows 10 and trying to use the package poLCA.

Here is my code:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(MASS)
library(poLCA)

data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)

data[-3] <- lapply(data[-3],gsub,pattern = "1", replacement = "2", fixed = TRUE)
data[-3] <- lapply(data[-3],gsub,pattern = "0", replacement = "1", fixed = TRUE)
cols.num<- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
data[cols.num] <- sapply(data[cols.num],as.numeric)

AMER_all <- data[which(data$SALES_LEVEL_1 == "AMERICAS"),]
AMER_ALL_LSA <- cbind("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
AMER_less_1000 <- AMER_all[which(AMER_all$WALLET_BINS == "<$2k"),]

AMER_less_1000_LCA <- poLCA(AMER_ALL_LSA, data = AMER_less_1000, nclass = 3, graphs = TRUE)
```

This is the error that I'm getting -

```
Error in runif(R * K.j[j]) : invalid arguments
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

and when I look at the warning I get this:

```
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any idea on why I'm getting this error? I'm wondering if its the version of R that I downloaded. I recently needed to reimage my laptop and download R and RStudio from fresh again..

Sample Data

```
structure(list(ï..COMPANY_ID = c("GUC_123", 
"GUC_111", "GUC_112", "GUC_113", "GUC_114", 
"GUC_115", "GUC_116", "GUC_117", 
"GUC_118", "GUC_119", "GUC_120", "GUC_121", 
"GUC_122", "GUC_123", "GUC_124", 
"GUC_125", "GUC_126", "GUC_127", 
"GUC_128", "GUC_129"), SALES_LEVEL_1 = c("AMERICAS", 
"APJC__", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "APJC__", "AMERICAS", "EMEAR-REGION", 
"AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "EMEAR-REGION", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", 
"AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "EMEAR-REGION", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", 
"AMERICAS", "APJC__", "EMEAR-REGION"), WALLET_BIN = c("$1k-$15k", 
"$15k-$50", "$1k-$15k", "$100k-$200k", "$1k-$15k", "$15k-$50", 
"$1k-$15k", "$1k-$15k", "$15k-$50", "$15k-$50", "$1k-$15k", "$1k-$15k", 
"$15k-$50", "$1k-$15k", "$1k-$15k", "$50k-$100k", "$50k-$100k", 
"$15k-$50", "$50k-$100k", "$1k-$15k"), A = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), B = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), C = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), D = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), E = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), F = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), G = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), H = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), I = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), J = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), K = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), L = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), M = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), N = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), O = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), P = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated with data sample

Comment: I notice that there is a `ï` in your first column name, is that intended? Your provided data has no `AMER_all$WALLET_BINS == "<$2k"` so it cannot be used to run your code. Finally, the first argument of `poLCA` is supposed to be a formula. In the help file they very interestingly use `f <- cbind(A,B,C,D)~1`, is your formula correct? If this doesn't help you identify the issue, please provide details and working data so we can help.

Comment: Hi Ian - I'm not sure why that character is in the first column. I've attempted to create a new column name and it still shows up. Any idea why it's showing up?

I've updated the code to the following:
```
AMER_ALL_LSA <- cbind("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") ~1
```
It's still showing an error.. I'm thinking it might be that weird character at the first column...

Comment: No, it is quite sensitive. Sorry

Comment: So I managed to remove the character by adding a dummy column to the right of the CSV file, then removed that column using `data <- data[-1]` but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: When you mention above " Your provided data has no `AMER_all$WALLET_BINS == "<$2k"` so it cannot be used to run your code" the data does have this value, just not in the first 20 rows..

Comment: I can replace some of the sensitive information. How can I attach a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the very silly issue is defining the formula without quotation marks as also noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532513/13095326):

```
library(poLCA)
data <- read.delim("https://pastebin.com/raw/TNJNCxkH")
data[,5:ncol(data)] <- lapply(data[,5:ncol(data)],gsub,pattern = "1", replacement = "2", fixed = TRUE)
data[,5:ncol(data)] <- lapply(data[,5:ncol(data)],gsub,pattern = "0", replacement = "1", fixed = TRUE)
data[,5:ncol(data)] <- sapply(data[,5:ncol(data)],as.numeric)
AMER_all <- data[which(data$SALES_LEVEL_1 == "AMERICAS"),]
AMER_ALL_LSA <- cbind(PB_1,PB_2,PB_3,PB_4,PB_5)~1
AMER_less_1000_LCA <- poLCA(AMER_ALL_LSA, data = AMER_all, nclass = 3, graphs = TRUE)
#Conditional item response (column) probabilities,
# by outcome variable, for each class (row) 
#...
#========================================================= 
#Fit for 3 latent classes: 
#========================================================= 
#number of observations: 1016 
#number of estimated parameters: 17 
#residual degrees of freedom: 14 
#maximum log-likelihood: -1068.675  
#AIC(3): 2171.351
#BIC(3): 2255.052
#G^2(3): 1.362823 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
#X^2(3): 0.7509686 (Chi-square goodness of fit) 
# 
#ALERT: iterations finished, MAXIMUM LIKELIHOOD NOT FOUND
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I still need to limit my data to the Wallet bins.. When I add that additional piece of code, I get the same error. `AMER_less_1000 <- AMER_all[which(AMER_all$WALLET_BINS == "<$2k"),]`

Comment: The data you posted on pastebin doesn't have the bin `"<$2k"`. It does have `"<$1k"`, but there are only 5 rows.

Comment: OMG - just a dumb error! Thank you. I've been looking at this for too long! ha. Thank you for your help!